# Using For Loops and Arrays on Javascript to display phone number when name is entered

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I want to set up a prompt so that when a user enters a username, it will display the phone number for that username.

So far when I run the code below, all it returns is the first username.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var question1 = prompt("Enter the username of a friend")

var i = 5;

var friends = ["Luke M. ", " Chloe M. ", "Cindi G. ", "Pete D. ", "Lola D. "];
var number1 = ["888-888-8888 ", "000-000-0000 ", "111-111-1111 ", "222-222-2222 ", "333-333-3333 "];

for (var i = 0; i <= friends; i++) {

}

document.write(friends[i] + number1[i]);
```

Comment: Hi Jean! I tried this and instead it displayed the entire array instead of just the phone number for the specific person I entered in the prompt. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @mrsmcd have a look at my answer I believe it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

- you must put your document.write inside the for loop
- use friends.length instead of i since i is the index number not the length of the array
- use the .length to get the length of the array friends
- Your array has white spaces in the string elements you may want to trim to check for spacing issues withm .trim()

**EDIT**
- Also when using a for loop and starting at 0 use 'less than' to not get an off by one error.

```js
var question1 = prompt("Enter the username of a friend")

 var friends = ["Luke M. ", " Chloe M. ", "Cindi G. ", "Pete D. ", "Lola D. "];
 var number1 = ["888-888-8888 ", "000-000-0000 ", "111-111-1111 ", "222-222-2222 ", "333-333-3333 "];

 for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
    if(question1 == friends[i].trim() || question1 == friends[i]){
         document.write( number1[i] );
     }
 }
```

**edited to only show number not name**

Comment: @mrsmcd Note that this method is case sensitive and you should convert to lowercase and check again if you want case insensitive. Glad we could help.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use array's `indexOf` function:

```
var friendIndex = friends.indexOf(question1);

if (friendIndex > -1) {
  document.write( friends[friendIndex ] + number1[friendIndex ] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `forEach()` method:

```js
var question1 = prompt("Enter the username of a friend")

 var friends = ["Luke M. ", " Chloe M. ", "Cindi G. ", "Pete D. ", "Lola D. "];
 var number1 = ["888-888-8888 ", "000-000-0000 ", "111-111-1111 ", "222-222-2222 ", "333-333-3333 "];

friends.forEach(function(friend, i) {
  if(friend.trim() === question1) {
    document.write( number1[i] );  
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because you don't have any code executing in the `for` loop.

If you do this:

```js
 var question1 = prompt("Enter the username of a friend")

 var i = 5;

 var friends = ["Luke M. ", " Chloe M. ", "Cindi G. ", "Pete D. ", "Lola D. "];
 var number1 = ["888-888-8888 ", "000-000-0000 ", "111-111-1111 ", "222-222-2222 ", "333-333-3333 "];

for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
  if(question1 === friends[i].trim()){
     document.write( friends[i] + ':' +  number1[i] );
   }    
}
```

Then, I believe that you will have what you are looking for.

(Of course, you will need to modify the above code to have it do what you need it to do aside from dumping the name.)

NOTE: The conditional in the for loop `i < friends.length` was modified from your original code as the array index has the range 0..friends.length - 1.

Comment: OP wants to match the name inputted with a value in the friends array and return the corresponding phone number. Not print out everything in both arrays.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  OP specifically asked "What am I doing wrong?"  The problem was the loop

Comment: Hi! I tried this and it did not return anything once I typed the name in the prompt...

Comment: Updated solution